# Form input focus border radius and input submit focus

Tags: css

I am trying to make the input focus border radius 5px but it stays square. Also trying to take away the border on the input button. It is the same as the input focus. I do not know how to do it. Ii looked online and could not find the answer. Thanks for any and all help you can give me.

I am trying to make the input focus border radius 5px but it stays square. Also trying to take away the border on the input button. It is the same as the input focus. I do not know how to do it. Ii looked online and could not find the answer. Thanks for any and all help you can give me.

```css
form {
margin-top: 50px;
}

input[type=text] {
border: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #242527; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: 300;
margin: 8px 0;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 12px 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 400px;
}

input:focus {
border-radius: 5px!important;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
outline: 1px solid #196477;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

textarea {
border: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #242527; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: 300;
margin: 8px 0;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 12px 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 400px;
}

textarea:focus {
border-radius: 5px!important;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
outline: 1px solid #196477;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
background-color: #8dc63f;  
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none;    
border-radius: 5px;
border-right-style: none;   
border-top-style: none;
box-sizing: border-box; 
color: #ffffff; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 600;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
opacity: 1.0;
padding: 10px;  
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 400px;   
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
background-color: #8dc63f!important;    
border-bottom-style: none!important;
border-left-style: none!important;  
border-radius: 5px!important;
border-right-style: none!important; 
border-top-style: none!important;
box-sizing: border-box!important;   
color: #ffffff!important;   
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif!important;
font-size: 18px!important;
font-weight: 600!important;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box!important;  
opacity: 0.9!important;
padding: 10px!important;    
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box!important;
width: 400px!important;
}
```

```html
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_contact.php">
<label for="first_name">First Name: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" autocomplete="off"/>
</br>
</br>
<label for="last_name">Last Name: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" autocomplete="off"/>
</br>
</br>
<label for="email">Email: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"/>
</br></br>
<label for="subject">Subject: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" autocomplete="off"/>
</br>
</br>
<label for="comments">Comments: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<textarea name="comments" cols="50" rows="8" id="comments" autocomplete="off"/></textarea>
</br>
</br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</br>
</br>
<p><font color="red">*</font> Indicates required fields
</br>Thank You
</br>The  Support Team</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed outline property from input:focus class works
For button outline: none

```css
form {
margin-top: 50px;
}

input[type=text] {
border: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #242527; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: 300;
margin: 8px 0;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 12px 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 400px;
}

input:focus {
border-radius: 5px!important;
outline: none;
border: 1px solid red;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

textarea {
border: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #242527; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: 300;
margin: 8px 0;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 12px 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 400px;
}

textarea:focus {
border-radius: 5px!important;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
outline: none;
 border: 1px solid red;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
background-color: #8dc63f;  
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none;    
border-radius: 5px;
border-right-style: none;   
border-top-style: none;
box-sizing: border-box; 
color: #ffffff; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 600;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
opacity: 1.0;
padding: 10px;  
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 400px;   
outline: none;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
background-color: #8dc63f!important;    
border-bottom-style: none!important;
border-left-style: none!important;  
border-radius: 5px!important;
border-right-style: none!important; 
border-top-style: none!important;
box-sizing: border-box!important;   
color: #ffffff!important;   
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif!important;
font-size: 18px!important;
font-weight: 600!important;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box!important;  
opacity: 0.9!important;
padding: 10px!important;    
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box!important;
width: 400px!important;
}
```

```html
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_contact.php">
<label for="first_name">First Name: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" autocomplete="off"/>
</br>
</br>
<label for="last_name">Last Name: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" autocomplete="off"/>
</br>
</br>
<label for="email">Email: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"/>
</br></br>
<label for="subject">Subject: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" autocomplete="off"/>
</br>
</br>
<label for="comments">Comments: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<textarea name="comments" cols="50" rows="8" id="comments" autocomplete="off"/></textarea>
</br>
</br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</br>
</br>
<p><font color="red">*</font> Indicates required fields
</br>Thank You
</br>The  Support Team</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I make the focus border a certain color. Thanks

Comment: please check updated code snippet above. I have given outline: none and border: 1px solid red; you can give whatever color you want

Comment: Did it only for  input:focus, you can replicate the same for other styles

Comment: Thanks but how can I stop my focus border from going around my submit. Thanks

Comment: removed the outline from submit button, you can validate in the above snippet

Comment: The way it is now the submit has no border which is great but the comments area is square again. Thanks

Comment: Since comment is not input it is textarea, so will update the above snippet.

Comment: now you can check comments area i.e textarea element too

Answer (score 0):

first for remove outline of your input use  **outline: none;**  and for focus pseudo-class use **border-color: #696969;**

```css
form {
margin-top: 50px;
}

input[type=text] {
border: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #242527; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: 300;
margin: 8px 0;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 12px 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 400px;
}

input:focus {

border-radius: 5px!important;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-color: #696969; 
}

textarea {
outline:none;
border: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #242527; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: 300;
margin: 8px 0;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 12px 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 400px;
}

textarea:focus {
border-radius: 5px!important;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-color: #696969; 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
background-color: #8dc63f;  
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none;    
border-radius: 5px;
border-right-style: none;   
border-top-style: none;
box-sizing: border-box; 
color: #ffffff; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 600;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
opacity: 1.0;
padding: 10px;  
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 400px;    
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
background-color: #8dc63f!important;    
border-bottom-style: none!important;
border-left-style: none!important;  
border-radius: 5px!important;
border-right-style: none!important; 
border-top-style: none!important;
box-sizing: border-box!important;   
color: #ffffff!important;   
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif!important;
font-size: 18px!important;
font-weight: 600!important;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box!important;  
opacity: 0.9!important;
padding: 10px!important;    
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box!important;
width: 400px!important;
}
```

```html
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_contact.php">
<label for="first_name">First Name: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" autocomplete="off"/>
</br>
</br>
<label for="last_name">Last Name: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" autocomplete="off"/>
</br>
</br>
<label for="email">Email: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"/>
</br></br>
<label for="subject">Subject: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" autocomplete="off"/>
</br>
</br>
<label for="comments">Comments: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<textarea name="comments" cols="50" rows="8" id="comments" autocomplete="off"/></textarea>
</br>
</br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</br>
</br>
<p><font color="red">*</font> Indicates required fields
</br>Thank You
</br>The  Support Team</p>
</div>
```